# Woocommerce Ajax is Not working on Checkout

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have to re-calculate the shipping costs after the postcode box is filled in, but it seems only to work when I am logged in as admin

```
function custom_checkbox_checker () {
global $woocommerce;
if ( is_checkout() ) {

$woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies(true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready( function (e) {

var $ = jQuery;
jQuery( "#billing_postcode").change(function() {

  $( document.body ).trigger( 'shipping_postcode' );

});


})


</script>
<?php }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkbox_checker', 50 );
```

Comment: Ok I can add that the code is in the footer and that I have all plugins except WooCommerce and Woo Table rates disabled. I have also tested the issue is different themes including twentytwelve

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are caching this javascript? Without more details there is not much I can tell you other than that your code is correct. Can you visit the page and inject the following into your JS console while not logged in? And see if it works.

```
jQuery( "#billing_postcode").change(function() {

  $( document.body ).trigger( 'shipping_postcode' );

});
```

Comment: Hi, I have cache disabled in the browser and webpage header meta.

The code makes no difference unfortunately.